# I want to change the link color randomly when i click on it. Is there any way i can do it without using buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

```
                <div class="heading">                  
                    <div id="link"><a>My Name</a></div>
                    <div class="pro">My Career</div>
                </div>
```

I tried to search for an answer but am just getting how to only change the background or with a button.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please share what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the link element.
2. Add a click listener to it.
3. On click of the link element, generate a random color and update the element's `color style attribute`.

Here is the demo-

```js
// find the link element
let linkEl = document.querySelector('#link a');

// attach a click listener to it
linkEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Generate a random color
  let color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  // set color to the link element
  linkEl.style.color = color;
})
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">                  
  <div id="link">
    <a>My Name (click me to change my color)</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pro">My Career</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This really works and is also understandable i tired it and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Yea probably

```
<script>
    function changeLinkColor() {
        // Generate a random color in the format '#RRGGBB'
        let randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

        // Get the link element
        let link = document.querySelector("#link a");

        // Set the link color to the random color
        link.style.color = randomColor;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really understanding this. A bit explanation would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in any case:

```js
function generateColor(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.anchor').forEach(el => {
      el.onclick = function(e){e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ generateColor() + ',' + generateColor() + ','+ generateColor() + ')';
  }
});
```

```css
.anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  background:dodgerblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:10px
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor anchor1" href="#">click 1</a>
<div class="anchor anchor2" href="#">click 1</div>
<p class="anchor anchor3" href="#">click 1</p>
```

Please check this solution and let me know if its help you in any way.

Comment: This code is actually only changing the link background color, and i just want to exactly change the link text color when i click on it.

Comment: just change the property by backgroundColor with color e.g. `e.target.style.color = ...`

Comment: Wow, I mean thanks for the explanation this code really works i had to change e.target.style.backgroundColor = ... to e.target.style.color = ...